# HTML export: Customize footer

Tags: export, html

If I export a notebook to [HTML](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/HTML.html), this is inserted at the end of every page:

```html
<div style="font-family:Helvetica; font-size:11px; width:100%; border:1px none #999999; border-top-style:solid; padding-top:2px; margin-top:20px;">
 <a href="http://www.wolfram.com/language/" style="color:#000; text-decoration:none;">
  <span style="color:#555555">Created with the Wolfram Language</span> 
 </a>
</div>
```

Is there a way to remove or customize this footer, *without* post-processing the generated HTML?  I am hoping for an undocumented option to customize the footer.

Comment: In the installation directory there's this binary dump file 
`/SystemFiles/Kernel/SystemResources/Linux-x86-64/Convert/HTMLConvert.mx`
that contains the ` ..Created with the Wolfram Language</span>` ` thing but I do not know if we can modify a binary file with a string replacement